# How do I Map through object of Objects[Vuejs]

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a mapping function as below :

```js
export const mapMetricsToValue: any = {
    item1: {
        0: 'green--text',
        0.3: 'red--text',
        0.45: 'orange--text',
    },
    item2:{
        0: 'yellow--text',
        0.5: 'blue--text',
        0.65: 'purple--text',
    }
};

export function getTextClass(metric: string, value: Number): string {
    return mapMetricsToValue(metric,value);
}
```

The idea is there can be different items(item1, item2...) and for each of these item values, there is a threshold color to define.. For eg :
    for item1:

```
-if (0<item1<0.3) it should return green, 
-if(0.3<item1<0.45) it should return red,
-else it should return orange
```

for item2, these thresholds are different and different colors.
I want to create a function (getTextClass) which will return the color on the basis of the item and its threshold

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I would always recommend being able to adhere to a type/interface where possible. I would suggest extracting Metric and its container to interfaces like so:

```
export interface Metric {
    lowerBound: number;
    color: string;
}
```

```
export interface MetricItem {
    name: string;
    metrics: Metric[];
}
```

This way, you're more easily able to refer to these values by name if you need them later. We would then create `mapMetricsToValue` like so:

```
export const mapMetricsToValue: MetricItem[] = [
    {
        name: 'item1',
        metrics: [
            {
                lowerBound: 0,
                color: 'green'
            },
            {
                lowerBound: 0.3,
                color: 'red'
            }, //...
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item2',
        metrics: [
            {
                lowerBound: 0,
                color: 'yellow'
            } //...
        ]
    }
];
```

And then determining which colour maps to a given value would be as simple as iterating over the array of values for a given `MetricItem` and checking if the given value is greater than the current `lowerBound` and the next `lowerBound`. This if course will only work if the values are already ordered by `lowerBound` ascending, but this can be always be sorted by another function if required.

```
export function getTextClass(metric: MetricItem, value: number) : string {
    let metrics = metric.metrics;
    let len = metrics.length;

    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let currentMetric = metrics[i];

        //if it's the last item in the array then we know it's above the lower bound
        if(i === len - 1) {
            return currentMetric.color;
        }

        let nextMetric = metrics[i + 1];

        if(currentMetric.lowerBound <= value && nextMetric.lowerBound > value) {
            return currentMetric.color;
        }
    }
}
```

To find the correct metric from it's name, we could use the following function:

```
export function findMetricByName(name: string, metrics: MetricItem[]): MetricItem {
    return metrics.find(metric => metric.name === name);
}
```

Comment: Very informative.. Implemented with Interface and it works.. Thanks a lot